# Replace Matrix elements with 1

Tags: python

I have an empty matrix and I want to replace the matrix elements with 1 if country (index) belongs to Region (column).

I try to create a double loop, but I get stacked when I need to do the conditional. Thanks. ([152 rows x 6 columns]). Thanks so much.

```
                          west europe  east europe  latin america  
Norway                              0            0              0   
Denmark                             0            0              0   
Iceland                             0            0              0   
Switzerland                         0            0              0   
Finland                             0            0              0   
Netherlands                         0            0              0   
Sweden                              0            0              0   
Austria                             0            0              0   
Ireland                             0            0              0   
Germany                             0            0              0   
Belgium                             0            0              0
```

I was thinking smth like:

```
matrix = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, size=(152, 6)), index=['# enumarate all the countries], columns=['west europe', 'east europe', 'latin america','north america','africa', 'asia'])
print (matrix)
for i in range (len(matrix)):
    for j in range(len(matrix)):
        if data[i] =='Africa' and data['Country'] = [ '#here enumarate all Africa countries':
           matrix[i][j]==1
      elif:
          .... 
           matrix[i][j]==1
      else:
           matrix[i][j]==0
print (matrix)


Sample data frame with countries and region:
    Country Happiness Rank  Happiness Score Economy Family  Health  Freedom Generosity  Corruption  Dystopia    Job Satisfaction    Region
0   Norway  1   7.537   1.616463    1.533524    0.796667    0.635423    0.362012    0.315964    2.277027    94.6    Western Europe
1   Denmark 2   7.522   1.482383    1.551122    0.792566    0.626007    0.355280    0.400770    2.313707    93.5    Western Europe
2   Iceland 3   7.504   1.480633    1.610574    0.833552    0.627163    0.475540    0.153527    2.322715    94.5    Western Europe
3   Switzerland 4   7.494   1.564980    1.516912    0.858131    0.620071    0.290549    0.367007    2.276716    93.7    Western Europe
4   Finland 5   7.469   1.443572    1.540247    0.809158    0.617951    0.245483    0.382612    2.430182    91.2    Western Europe
5   Netherlands 6   7.377   1.503945    1.428939    0.810696    0.585384    0.470490    0.282662    2.294804    93.8    Western Europe
```

Comment: Do you have some sort of dictionary that maps countries to regions?

Comment: yes, i have a table where there are 2 columns with the name of the country and the region.

Comment: Are you using/willing to use pandas?

Comment: @Cata Can you just add that 2 column table to the question. You can get to your output table directly from there with `pd.get_dummies`

Answer (score 2):

If your input variable `data` is a DataFrame, then as @Alollz mentioned, you can use the pandas [pd.get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) function.

Something like this: `pd.get_dummies(data, columns=['Region'])`

And the output would look like:

```
    Country     HappinessRank   HappinessScore  Economy     Family  Health  Freedom     Generosity  Corruption  Dystopia    JobSatisfaction     Region_WesternEurope
0   Norway  1   7.537   1.616463    1.533524    0.796667    0.635423    0.362012    0.315964    2.277027    94.6    1
1   Denmark     2   7.522   1.482383    1.551122    0.792566    0.626007    0.355280    0.400770    2.313707    93.5    1
2   Iceland     3   7.504   1.480633    1.610574    0.833552    0.627163    0.475540    0.153527    2.322715    94.5    1
3   Switzerland     4   7.494   1.564980    1.516912    0.858131    0.620071    0.290549    0.367007    2.276716    93.7    1
4   Finland     5   7.469   1.443572    1.540247    0.809158    0.617951    0.245483    0.382612    2.430182    91.2    1
5   Netherlands     6   7.377   1.503945    1.428939    0.810696    0.585384    0.470490    0.282662    2.294804    93.8    1
```

It will take the `Region` category column and make it into indicator columns. In this case it uses the column name as the prefix but you can play around with that.